# AWS Lambda Function ( versionamento e integração com API Gateway )

Tags: expressões-lambda, amazon-aws, api

**Problemas com versionamento do lambda**:

1. Tenho uma função lambda onde utilizo variáveis de ambiente.
2. Essa função é executada por um endpoint através do API Gateway ( aws )
3. Tenho 3 estágios do mesmo recurso ( Api Gateway ): dev, hom, prod
4. Tenho que alterar a variável de ambiente do lambda de acordo com o estágio que está invocando a função.

> O problema é que, como todos os estágios chamam a mesma função lambda, ambos estágios utilizam a versão do lambda em **produção**, nas variáveis de ambiente eu defino a conexão com o banco de dados, preciso que essa conexão mude de acordo com o estágio que chamou a função. Tentei fazer o versionamento da função porém tive o problema de não poder mudar a variável de ambiente na versão, apenas é possível mudar na ***master***.

Segue imagens explicativas do problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar três funções lambda, cada uma com suas próprias variáveis de ambiente definidas? Você tem a vantagem ai de evoluir seu código sem impactar a função rodando em produção

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juntando algumas informações obtidas aqui no stackoverflow e no blog da AWS, consegui resolver o problema da seguinte maneira.

1. Defini variáveis de estágio 
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Criei variáveis de ambiente na minha função lambda, especificando o nome do banco de dados de cada ambiente (estágio).
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. No código ( Go ), verifico as variáveis de estágio, de acordo com a variável modifico o nome do banco, conseguindo assim me conectar no banco de dados do estágio indicado.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Não é melhor você criar 3 lambdas diferentes (um pra cada ambiente), e no API Gateway usar o ARN do Lambda como variável de estágio?

Se a gente analisar:

Ambiente de dev (é onde você vai testar o seu código, e é um ambiente que você pode "quebrar" a vontade)

No seu caso, você tem o mesmo código rodando para os 3 ambientes. Se você subir alguma coisa que quebre o código, você derruba tudo.